# copy section/category while updating linked column

Tags: mysql, copy

I have two linked tables of section/category structure.

```
the section table structure
id sec_title
1  section 1
2  section 2

the category structure
id sectionid cat_title
1  1  cat1
2  1  cat2
3  2  cat 3
4  2  cat 4
```

is there an easy way to copy a section with all of its categories into the same section and categories table?

the problem if i do a straight copy is that the "sectionid" of the copied rows in the category table is not of the id of the new section rows. instead it is the sectionid of the old rows.

I need the "sectionid" to be of the ids of the new inserted section rows.

copied version

```
section table structure:

id sec_title
1  section 1
2  section 2
3  copy of section 1
4  copy of section 2

the category structure
id sectionid cat_title
1  1  cat1
2  1  cat2
3  2  cat 3
4  2  cat 4
5  3  cat1
6  3  cat2
7  4  cat 3
8  4  cat 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** You can clone several sections at once like this

```
INSERT INTO section (sec_title) 
SELECT CONCAT('Copy of ', sec_title)
  FROM section
 WHERE id IN(1, 2)
 ORDER BY id;

INSERT INTO category (sectionid, cat_title)
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() + rnum, cat_title
  FROM 
(
  SELECT sectionid, cat_title, @n := IF(@g = sectionid, @n + 1, 0) rnum, @g := sectionid
    FROM category CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := -1, @g := NULL) i
   WHERE sectionid IN (1, 2)
   ORDER BY sectionid, id
)q;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab25f/1)** demo

---

**Answer to original question:**

> Is there an easy way to copy a section with all of its categories into the same section and categories table?

Assuming that `id` columns in both tables are `auto_increment` columns and you want to clone section 2 you can do it like this

```
INSERT INTO section (sec_title) 
SELECT CONCAT('Copy of ', sec_title)
  FROM section
 WHERE id = 2;
INSERT INTO category (sectionid, cat_title)
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), cat_title
  FROM category
 WHERE sectionid = 2;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87a2c/1)** demo

---

You can wrap it in a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE clone_section(IN _sectionid INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO section (sec_title) 
  SELECT CONCAT('Copy of ', sec_title)
    FROM section
   WHERE id = _sectionid;
  INSERT INTO category (sectionid, cat_title)
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), cat_title
    FROM category
   WHERE sectionid = _sectionid;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it

```
CALL clone_section(2);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b31c2/1)** demo

Comment: would this work also if there were multiple section rows being added in one statement? i.e. if the first statement is "SELECT blah FROM SECTIONS WHERE user_id=3" so that there are multiple sections inserted. see above where two section rows were copied and four category rows.

Comment: No it won't work with several sections at once. But you didn't mentioned that **important** detail in your original question. Nothing in your question implies your intent to clone several sections at once.

Comment: See updated answer. You can substitute `IN(1, 2)` with `IN(SELECT id FROM sections WHERE ...)` in both inserts.